# Get the required module names for Lua

Tags: lua

Is there a way to check what modules is required by a lua script
after I loaded it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More of a hack than a real solution: if you control the hosting environment, you can always replace `require` with your version of it:

```
local require_original = require

function require(module)
    -- do something with the module name
    require_original(module)
end
```

Comment: This might seem like a hack to a Java programmer, but in Lua it seems perfectly normal and may be a good solution.  I'd give it +2 if I could.

Comment: @Jon: It is a hack for a given task — given a presence of `package.loaded`  in the official API.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [package.loaded](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaded) table.

Comment: Try `for name in pairs(package.loaded) do print(name) end`.

Comment: The trouble is that this will return *all* loaded packages, not just those loaded by one module.

Comment: @Stuart: you can always compare its values before and after a single require. The difference is a list of packages, loaded by that require.